# Is it possible to 'Like' a page without it appearing in your Facebook profile? (Without hiding the category that page is in)

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, profile

I'm trying to 'Like' a certain page, but I don't want it to appear in the 'Info' part of my Facebook Profile. Is this possible without hiding the category that the page is in, or to move the 'Liked' page to the 'Other Pages You Like' category?

Currently, I can only do this on pages that appear in the 'Activities' category. It has an X 'close' button for each activity, that when clicked, prompts me if I want to remove that page from my Profile. Once removed from the Profile, this page will still appear liked. (Tested with the [Megaupload page](https://www.facebook.com/pages/Megaupload/108268122527887).)

I, however, can't do this with the other categories, like Music, which doesn't have a close button for each page. If Facebook decides that a page I liked should go to the 'Music' part of my Profile, I have to 'Unlike' it to remove it from my Profile. This means that I can't change the category of a 'Liked' page or put it in the 'Other Pages You Like' category (which can be hidden separately from the other categories in the Profile).

Note: I'm not using [Timeline](https://www.facebook.com/about/timeline).

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible to do this. (Also, your profile will be converted to Timeline soon.)

Answer (score 2):

If you follow these points, it will work:

- Go to the Likes page of your profile and click Edit.
- Remove your embarrassing like from its category by hovering over it
  and clicking the "X" that shows up.
- Scroll down to one of the other categories that you don't use—like
  "Sports Teams," "Video Games," or "Inspirational People"—and change
  its privacy setting to "Only Me."
- Next, add your embarrassing likes to that category. Even if they
  don't fit—say, adding Taylor Swift to Sports Teams—Facebook will
  still let you add them there.
- Click the "Done Editing" button at the top of your page and continue
  using Facebook as normal.